# Setting beginning and end parameters to a JavaScript slideshow

Tags: javascript

I'm no JavaScript expert, so if this is not the best method that is probably why. I have built a functional slideshow using these JavaScript functions:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function shiftLeft() {
        var val = (parseInt(document.getElementById('slides').style.left, 10) || 0) + 560;
        document.getElementById('slides').style.left = val + 'px';
    }
    function shiftRight () {
        var val = (parseInt(document.getElementById('slides').style.left, 10) || 0) - 560;
        document.getElementById('slides').style.left = val + 'px';
    }
</script>
```

Basically, this shifts the image 560 pixels one way or the other depending on if the left or right button is clicked. Everything is working as expected at this point, however I am looking to add in parameters to prevent the slide from sliding any further than 0px (i.e. on positive integers) and no farther than -3360 px. Any advice into how to set these parameters into effect? Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you set `val`, check it first to see if it exceeds its limit:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var leftBound = 0,
      rightBound = -3360;
  function shiftLeft() {
    var val = (parseInt(document.getElementById('slides').style.left, 10) || 0) + 560;
    val = val > leftBound ? leftBound : val;
    document.getElementById('slides').style.left = val + 'px';
  }
  function shiftRight () {
    var val = (parseInt(document.getElementById('slides').style.left, 10) || 0) - 560;
    val = val < rightBound ? rightBound : val;
    document.getElementById('slides').style.left = val + 'px';
  }
</script>
```

I even made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a3ahxj96/1/).

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function shiftLeft(min, max) {
    var val = (parseInt(document.getElementById('slides').style.left, 10) || 0) + 560;
    if (val<min) {val=min;} else if (val > max) {val=max;}
    document.getElementById('slides').style.left = val + 'px';
}
function shiftRight (min, max) {
    var val = (parseInt(document.getElementById('slides').style.left, 10) || 0) - 560;
    if (val<min) {val=min;} else if (val > max) {val=max;}
    document.getElementById('slides').style.left = val + 'px';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight. The main issue I experienced with this is the slide disappeared at the min and max parameters. But very informative in my pursuit for understanding. Thanks for you help!